# How to delete a template from the "New" menu?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-template

I recently added a new Word document template in the "+ New" menu using "+ Add Template". It worked great.

However, I now have a newer version of this template and would like to remove the old one. How can I do that? I can't see an option to remove it, nor find the template anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check as following to delete the template:

[image]